# how to create 2 column and set AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

im trying to create 2 column and set auto_increment i already create 1 column and set auto_increment and 2nd column showing error to set auto_increment

how can i create 2 column and set auto_increment
please help me to fix this issue
thanks

SQL query:

```
ALTER TABLE  `admission` CHANGE  `rollno`  `rollno` INT( 8 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

MySQL said:

> #1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: That's right - you can only have one autoincrement column in a table - why would you ever need a second?

Comment: What the point to have 2 such fields ? Both fields will have the same difference.

Comment: Do you want to fill an existing column with incrementing values?

Answer (score 0):

Just like the error says you can only have one auto_increment column.  It seems to me that since the values of the two columns would most likely always be identical you can just use the one column.  If that's not the case then it's up to you to either iterate that column manually , or you can create an `INSERT` trigger on the table that sets the new column either to the other `auto_increment`'s value or to whatever value it's supposed to be (max + 1)?